# Using an If Statement to return value based on different integers

Tags: python

I'm a newbie. I want to put a condition on numbers. If I check one number, it works fine. But if I want it to return the same value for two differ)

```
for row in row2:
  if int ==  1: 
    return = "Music"
```

but I want to expand it further to include other numbers. So,

```
for row in row2:
  if int ==  1 , 2: 
    return = "Music"
```

I've also tried using or in the second option but it didn't work. Any help to check different integers to bring back a certain result would be great.

Comment: Check this out [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Comment: Don't try to use standard Python names like `int` and `return` as variables.  In the case of `int` you will be masking the builtin definition, and in the case of `return` you will get a syntax error.  Try to work with the language, as opposed to fighting it.

Answer (score 2):

To test multiple values:

```
if i in (1, 2):
```

Note that `return` is a keyword and you can't assign a value to it.
`int` is a predefined identifier; you can assign a value to it, but you
really don't want to; it will confuse things terribly.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean

```
for row in row2:
    if int == 1 and 2: 
        return = "Music"
```

or

```
for row in row2:
    if int in (1 , 2): 
        return = "Music"
```

Also, `int` is a built-in function name. So don't use it as a variable name. And `return = "Music"` is `invalid syntax` because `return` is a keyword in Python. Maybe you mean `return "Music"`.

Comment: I like more the second one, more scalable.

Comment: @Kevin Guan The second one works perfect!! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Three mistakes in your code

- `int` is a type, shouldn't use it as a variable name
- The syntax for your if statement is wrong
- You shouldn't use an `=` when returning

What you want is probably:

```
if row in (1,2):
    return "Music"
```

Or

```
if row == 1 or row == 2:
    return "Music"
```

Comment: Yes. That makes sense. Thank you!